# is an empty set an element of {empty set}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am on set section right now and I have questions about empty set

is an empty set an element of {empty set}?
is an empty set a subset of {empty set}?
is an empty set a proper subset of {empty set}?

I am just wondering because on the textbook didn't mention about these three? please bear with me I am really doubt a lot of things.

I got the questions online and I am practicing it right now so please

> correct me if I am wrong. 
>   a) {empty set} is an element of {empty set} = false 
>   b) {empty set} is a subset of {empty set} = false 
>   c) empty set is an element of {empty set,{empty set}}= true 
>   d) {empty set} is an element of {{empty set}} = true 
>   e) {{empty set}}is a proper subset of {empty set,{empty set}} = false

I hope I get em all right after you explained to me.

thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"is an empty set an element of {empty set}?"

Yes, the set {empty set} is a set with a single element. The single element is the empty set.  {empty set} is *NOT* the same thing as the empty set.

" is an empty set a subset of..."  STOP!!! The empty set is a subset of *EVERY* set.  (Because the empty set has no elements so all zero of its elements are in every other set.  Or if you take A and B, A $\subset$ B means A doesn't have any elements not in B.  The element doesn't have any elements not in B so empty set $\subset B and it doesn't matter what B is.

"is an empty set a proper subset of ..." Yes.  A proper subset is a subset that isn't the same set.  empty set is not {empty set} so it is a proper subset.

Comment: then is {empty set} an element of  {empty set} ? it is not right?

Comment: @guest1, $\{\emptyset\}\not\in\{\emptyset\}$ because the only element of $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: The thing we are getting at is having a set as a member of another set, is not at all the same thing as have the elements of the set be a member of the other set.  The {{banana, orange}, fred the dinosaur, 7} has exactly 3 members; the number 7, fred the dinosaur, and the set {banana, orange}.  It does *not* actually have either banana or orange as a member. It has a set that contains banana and orage but it is the *set* that is the member.  Not banana or orange.  Same thing as {empty set} which is a set with exactly one member.

Answer (score 3):

A empty set {} has no entries... It is subset of every other set  but a set containing the empty set is not empty anymore ... (It contains the empty set)